# what to use instead of an empty Div around textbox

Tags: html, css, sass

I have several input boxes, that align like this:

[image]

My code has empty div around it like:

```
  <form class="add-user"
    [formGroup]="addUserForm">


<div class="add-user__container">

        <div>
        <input
            class="add-user__input"
            formControlName="firstName"
            label="First Name"
            type="text"
            placeholder="First Name"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input
            class="add-user__input"
            formControlName="lastName"
            label="Last Name"
            placeholder="Last Name"
            type="text"/>
   </div>
   ....
```

when the validation comes, it will show like this:

[image]

But I need to remove that empty Div that is around the input, when I remove it after validation input boxes are not align. what can I use instead of an empty div?

[image]

this is my CSS:

```
.add-user {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr;
gap: toRem(10px) 0;



// .add-user__item
&__item {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: toRem(228px) toRem(177px) 1fr;
    gap: toRem(10px);
    color: $color-alizarin;
    margin-top: toRem(10px);
}

// .add-user__container
&__container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: toRem(12px);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could simply use the label as a wrapper instead of the divs:

```css
.add-user__container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="add-user__container">
  <label>
    First Name
    <input class="add-user__input" 
           formControlName="firstName"
           type="text"
           placeholder="First Name">
  </label>
  <label>
    Last Name
    <input class="add-user__input" 
           formControlName="lastName"
           type="text"
           placeholder="last Name">
  </label>
  <label>
    Email Adress
    <input class="add-user__input" 
           formControlName="emailAdress"
           type="text"
           placeholder="Email Adress">
  </label>
  <label>
    Role
    <input class="add-user__input" 
           formControlName="role"
           type="text"
           placeholder="Read Only">
  </label>
</div>
```

Alternativly, you can simply declare a minimum height of the divs. that will prevent a height increase with the validation if the minimum height is high enough.